# AEM 6.2 How to switch from classic UI to Touch

Tags: user-interface, aem, author

How can we switch from classic UI to Touch UI in AEM 6.2.  I see documentation to switch from touch ui to classic but not other way round.

Comment: In 6.1 it wasn't there and we had to add a custom button in siteadmin which took the user to touch interface.

Answer (score 7):

**Site Wide**

In system console (http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr) there is an OSGi configuration for `WCM Authoring UI Mode Service`. You can change the property of `Default authoring UI mode` to `TOUCH`.

**Per User**

Login as the user, navigate to Projects (http://localhost:4502/projects.html/content/projects), select the user icon in the top right hand corner, select the settings icon, ensure that Authoring Mode has `Touch-Optimized` selected.

**Other Items**

You should also ensure the OSGi config for `Day CQ Root Mapping` has the property `Target Path` set to `/projects.html`

Comment: All these options are about setting the default option to touch but the question is about having an interface to switch from classic to touch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short cut to switch between the two UI modes: 
Open any page from Site Admin by default it will load in Touch UI Mode. The URL will be say http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/test.html. Now to switch to classic UI you would write http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/test.html. Replace 'cf#' in the URL with 'editor.html'.

Answer (score 0):

Three methods to do so are:-

1. [User Level]

[image]

2. [Global Level]Go to:-http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
   and choose WCM Authoring UI Mode Service

[image]

3. using cf# or editor.html
   If your site is :- http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html

then 
Classic UI :- http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html
Touch UI   :- http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html

Reference Adobe AEM Community posts:-
Link:-http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__isbp-hi_i_want_toope.html

Link:-http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__7rmk-i_was_askedtoconfi.html

I hope this will help you.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni

Comment: He's asking the other way around, what you are explaining is how to access Classic UI from Touch UI.  He's asking how to return to Touch UI from the Classic UI.  This isn't something that was implemented, AEM more or less abandoned the Classic UI and is not updating it anymore.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your valuable comments. Point 1 is Touch ui to Classic UI but Point 2,3 are both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Classic UI has been more or less abandoned since 6.1 and won't likely be updated anymore as Adobe is trying to move away from ExtJS.

That said what you could do is add a custom button to the sidekick that would navigate to the TouchUI, which would involves adding the editor.html at the root of the URL of the page (and removing the #cf if it's there)

You can follow this link that gives an example on how to add a new function to the Classic UI sidekick.
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-component1.html

Answer (score 0):

Nate Yolles has produced a Chrome Extension that allows switching between modes amongst other things

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aem-developer/hgjhcngmldfpgpakbnffnbnmcmohfmfc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog